# How to parse data that is being fetched from a text file?

Tags: php, regex

I am fetching data from a text file where I need to match the substring to get the matched line. Once, I have that, I need to get the third 8 digit value in the line which comes after the delimiter "|".  Basically, all the values have varying lengths and are separated by a delimiter "|". Except the first substring (id) which is of fixed length and has a fix starting and end position.

Text file data example:

```
    0123456|BHKAHHHHkk|12345678|JuiKKK121255
    9100450|HHkk|12348888|JuiKKK10000000021sdadad255
```

```
$file = 'file.txt';


// the following line prevents the browser from parsing this as HTML.
header('Content-Type: text/plain');

// get the file contents, assuming the file to be readable (and exist)
$contents = file_get_contents($file);
// escape special characters in the query
$txt = explode("\n",$contents);

$counter = 0;
foreach($txt as $key => $line){
    $subbedString = substr($line,2,6);

   // $searchfor = '123456';
    //echo strpos($subbedString,$searchfor); 
    if(strpos($subbedString,$searchfor) === 0){
        $matches[$key] = $searchfor;
        $matchesLine[$key] = substr($line,2,50);
          echo  "<p>" . $matchesLine[$key] . "</p>";
          
                  $counter += 1;
                  if($counter==10) break;
         
    }
```

Comment: why not just explode each line of the file and grab the 3rd index

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If you need to divide file's contents by line breaks, it's always better to use [file](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.file.php) function
2. To divide line into parts with unknown length by a delimiter, use [explode](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.explode.php) function.

**Code:**

```
$file = 'file.txt';
$txt = file($file);

$counter = 0;
foreach ($txt as $key => $line) {
    $line = \trim($line);
    $substrings = explode('|', $line);
    
    if (\count($substrings) === 0) {
        continue;
    }

    $searchFor = '123456';
    if (substr($substrings[0], 1) === $searchFor) {
        if (!isset($substrings[2]) {
            continue;
        }

        $matches[$key] = $searchFor;

        $matchesLine[$key] = $line;
        echo  "<p>" . $substrings[2] . "</p>";

        if (++$counter === 10) {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

I also noticed that in your example there are 7-digit ids, while you were talking about 6 digits (and the `$searchfor` variable didn't match anything)

Comment: the first digit is an indicator not part of the id.

Comment: @JackYuan I updated my answer

Comment: thank you for your help.

Comment: I would suggest to move the explode of $line to the part after you found out the id actually does match. Depending on how long the line is. The match using substr() can then be done if(substr($line, 1, 6) === $search)

Comment: @IvoP yes, it makes sense if id format will always be the same (1+6 digits), but who knows :)

Comment: One more question: If I simply want to get the second value in between the two delimiters. How can I do that? For example: 0123456|BHKAHHHHkk|12345678|JuiKKK121255 --> Output: BHKAHHHHkk

Answer (score 2):

Use

```php
^(\d+)\|[^|]*\|(\d{8})\|
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/7fFXmR/1).

**EXPLANATION**

```php
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times (matching
                             the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \|                       '|'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [^|]*                    any character except: '|' (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \|                       '|'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \2:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d{8}                    digits (0-9) (8 times)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \|                       '|'
```

**[Sample code](https://tio.run/##PU9Ni8IwEL3nV8xBsNVCk2rdiruIYlHsQenubauhbMO22EpIUy/G317Hzzcw8Ib35s3IXLbt51TmkpCOEvAFXXdvJVnfTszv3ux6iUF2Di7I3ao7IZ1aq5uKMm8w9EdmvopmK8ThYB6Tj8CsmyKKIuYxz/fJmFE69Kl5SwLES0Kf8FidpVhowAwilfjnVar/cp6WpYWHOXALxn6fitqBbRwu@Xf4wzfxIowdoDYaXRe2qjhq0LkAcdQFvnR3gBJ1U2pyShXPmkpar0X2pG2v)**:

```php
<?php

$re = '/^(\d+)\|[^|]*\|(\d{8})\|/m';
$str = '0123456|BHKAHHHHkk|12345678|JuiKKK121255
9100450|HHkk|12348888|JuiKKK10000000021sdadad255';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

// Print the entire match result
var_dump($matches);
```

**Sample output**:

```php
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(28) "0123456|BHKAHHHHkk|12345678|"
    [1]=>
    string(7) "0123456"
    [2]=>
    string(8) "12345678"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(22) "9100450|HHkk|12348888|"
    [1]=>
    string(7) "9100450"
    [2]=>
    string(8) "12348888"
  }
}
```

Comment: This regexp works indeed, but @JackYuan also needs to match the ids from the first column.

Comment: @Hast This seems easy to capture the first digits as well.